# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() MySQLi - WHERE MATCH $term

Tags: php, mysqli, sphinx

I am trying to query my database using Sphinx Search using MySQLi.

What I am trying to achieve is the user enters a Term, which is then used to query my database, and return the values. However I get the error:

"Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"

```
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'null', 'null', 'null', 9306); 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
throw new Exception('Connection Error: ['.$conn->connect_errno.'] '.$conn->connect_error, $conn->connect_errno);
}

$term = $_GET['q'];

echo "$term";  


$resource = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ($term)');
$results = array();
while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()) {
$results[] = $row;
}
$resource->free_result(); 

var_dump($results);
```

The offending line appears to be:

```
$resource = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ($term)');
```

If I change the line to:

```
$resource = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM test1')
```

The query runs fine, however I need the query to match $term however I am having issues doing so and I don't understand why.

Comment: And did you try the query that doesn't work on the client, to see what the server has to say about it?

Comment: Yes, apache error logs read:  "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" only when the $resource query uses the "WHERE MATCH"

Comment: I mean the MySql query. If you run it manually the server will tell you exactly what is wrong with it.

Comment: I got "expecting QUOTED_STRING". So does that mean I need to change ($term) to ('$term') as well as ('title', 'description')?

Comment: Yes. Also please be aware this code would be vulnerable to SQL injection if it worked as intended -- which it doesn't because `$term` is not interpolated in a single-quoted string, and because the value is unquoted.

Comment: Tried what you suggested, however it appears I'm going round in circles

Answer (score 1):

You're not quoting the stuff you're putting into your query.

And even if you were, it might not work anyway. Or, it might just delete your entire dataset! If you're putting user-entered data into a database, you have to be careful. Use a prepared query; if you want my advice, dump the mysqli API and move to something higher level like PDO.

```
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'null', 'null', 'null', 9306); 
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    throw new Exception('Connection Error: ['.$conn->connect_errno.'] '.$conn->connect_error, $conn->connect_errno);
}

$term = $_GET['q'];

echo "$term";  

$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST (?)');
$statement->bind_param("s", $term);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Okay I understand. I think a prepared query using PDO would be the way to go - however when using your example on line 10 where it reads "AGAINST ($term)" I get the error "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object"

Comment: Then there must be a problem with the call to `prepare()`. Is your database connection initializing properly? There should be error checking at each step of the way; I just took your code and changed it slightly. I'm not that experienced with using `mysqli_*` functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$resource = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ($term)');
```

Thats a **MySQL** query. Thats the syntax MySQL uses for running a full-text query.

You are connecting to Sphinx (port 9306 gives it away), so should be running **SphinxQL**.

Lookup the SphinxQL's `SELECT` syntax... 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select